# Failed to open stream on file_get_contents in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get file contents from a context resource repetitively with different type of id's. Every time I run the script error is occurring for various id's randomly and also giving the result for some of the cases.

```
<?php

$values = [5,6,9,12,18,20,25,30,32,36,37,38,40,42,45,47,49,50];
$result = [];

foreach($values as $value){
    $response = url_get_contents( "https://example.com/api?id=$value" );
    array_push( $result,$response );
}

print_r( $result );
```

The warning is

```
failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected
 party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
 connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

When I try to reflect the result in html in JSON format by making an ajax call to this file. The result in console looks like

```
{
    "18": {
        "rollnumber": "5",
        "status": false
    },
    "19": {
        "rollnumber": "6",
        "status": "Fail"
    },
    "20": {
        "rollnumber": "9",
        "status": "Fail"
    },
    "21": {
        "rollnumber": "12",
        "status": false
    },
    "22": {
        "rollnumber": "18",
        "status": false
    },
    "23": {
        "rollnumber": "20",
        "status": false
    },
    "24": {
        "rollnumber": "25",
        "status": "Pass"
    },
    "25": {
        "rollnumber": "30",
        "status": "Fail"
    },
    "26": {
        "rollnumber": "32",
        "status": "Pass"
    },
    "27": {
        "rollnumber": "36",
        "status": "Fail"
    },
    "28": {
        "rollnumber": "37",
        "status": false
    },
    "29": {
        "rollnumber": "38",
        "status": false
    },
    "30": {
        "rollnumber": "40",
        "status": "Pass"
    },
    "31": {
        "rollnumber": "42",
        "status": false
    },
    "32": {
        "rollnumber": "45",
        "status": false
    },
    "33": {
        "rollnumber": "47",
        "status": "Pass"
    },
    "34": {
        "rollnumber": "49",
        "status": "Pass"
    },
    "35": {
        "rollnumber": "50",
        "status": "Pass"
    }
}
```

Wherever the array value of status is false, the above mentioned error is occurring because file_get_contents is giving false. But, If I run it once again, the result will alter and in fact the previous result of status for roll number 5 was valid and now it is false. Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Maybe you requesting too fast and the server is rejecting you, you should add sleep(1)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working though. Tried adding but same error after a period of time.